# C# intersect a line bettween 2 Vector3 point on a plane

Tags: c#, vector, intersection

I have a line going bettween two Vector3 points and I want to find when the line is intersected at a height along the Z axis.

I am trying to write a function to calculate the intersection point.

```
void Main()
{
    Vector3 A = new Vector3(2.0f,  2.0f, 2.0f);
    Vector3 B = new Vector3(7.0f, 10.0f, 6.0f);
    float Z = 3.0f;

    Vector3 C = getIntersectingPoint(A, B, Z);
    //C should be X=3.25, Y=4.0, Z=3.0
}
```

But trying to figure out how to do the math to handle possible negative numbers correctly is really starting to confuse me.

This is what I have and the moment, but this isn't correct.

```
public static Vector3 getIntersectingPoint(Vector3 A, Vector3 B, float Z)
{
    // Assume z is bettween A and B and we don't need to validate
    // Get ratio of triangle hight, height Z divided by (Za to Zb)  
    ("absolute value: " + Math.Abs(A.Z-B.Z)).Dump();
    ("z offset: " + (Math.Abs(Z-B.Z)<Math.Abs(A.Z-Z)?Math.Abs(Z-B.Z):Math.Abs(A.Z-Z))).Dump();
    float ratio = (Math.Abs(Z-B.Z)<Math.Abs(A.Z-Z)?Math.Abs(Z-B.Z):Math.Abs(A.Z-Z))/Math.Abs(A.Z-B.Z);
    ("ratio: " + ratio.ToString()).Dump();
    float difX = ratio*Math.Abs(A.X-B.X);//this still needs to be added to or taken from the zero point offset
    ("difX: " + difX.ToString()).Dump();
    float difY = ratio*Math.Abs(A.Y-B.Y);//this still needs to be added to or taken from the zero point offset
    ("difY: " + difY.ToString()).Dump();

    float X = difX + (A.X<B.X?A.X:B.X);
    ("X: " + X).Dump();
    float Y = difY + (A.Y<B.Y?A.Y:B.Y);
    ("Y: " + Y).Dump();
    return new Vector3(X,Y,Z);
}
```

Does anyone know if there are any Math libraries that will already do this or examples that show how to do this that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the starting (2.0f) and ending (6.0f) Z coordinates. The Z distance between the two points is 4.0f. You want to know the X and Y coordinates at the point where Z is 3.0f.

Remember that Z changes *linearly* along the segment. The segment is 4 units long, The point you're interested in is 1 unit from the start, or 1/4 of the length of the segment.

The X distance of the entire segment is 7.0 - 2.0, or 5 units. 1/4 of 5 is 1.25, so the X coordinate at the intersection is 3.25.

The Y distance of the entire segment is 8. 1/4 of 8 is 2. So the Y coordinate of the intersection point is 6.0.

The intersection point is (3.25f, 6.0f, 3.0f).

How to compute:

```
// start is the starting point
// end is the ending point
// target is the point you're looking for.
// It's pre-filled with the Z coordinate.
zDist = Math.Abs(end.z - start.z);
zDiff = Math.Abs(target.z - start.z);
ratio = zDiff / zDist;

xDist = Math.Abs(end.x - start.x);
xDiff = xDist * ratio;
xSign = (start.x < end.x) ? 1 : -1;
target.x = start.x + (xDiff * xSign);

yDist = Math.Abs(end.y - start.y);
yDiff = yDist * ratio;
ySign = (start.y < end.y) ? 1 : -1;
target.y = start.y + (yDiff * ySign);
```

Come to think of it, the whole sign thing shouldn't be necessary. Consider this, when `end.x = 10` and `start.x = 18`:

```
xDist = end.x - start.x;      // xDist = -8
xDiff = xDist * ratio;        // xDiff = -2
target.x = start.x + xDiff;   // target.x = 18 + (-2) = 16
```

Yeah, no need for sign silliness.

Also no need for the calls to `Math.Abs` when computing the ratio. We know that `zDist` and `zDiff` will both have the same sign, so `ratio` will always be positive.